# jQuery date picker update available dates using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Attempting to have the jQuery Datepicker dynamically update after #tour_region field is changed.  I took this code from Salman's Web Blog and altered the CSS identifiers to mine and also, obviously, changed the url for the Ajax call.

When I built the JSON response I tested it using a .ajax call, but Salman had a .getJSON one.

The error I'm getting is: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entry' of undefined"

Makes me think maybe something is wrong with the JSON response.  I'm not too familiar with the .getJSON call.

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        var dateList = null;
        var date1 = new Date;
        date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        date1.setDate(1);
        var date2 = new Date;
        date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 12, 0);
        $("form #date").datepicker({
            minDate: date1,
            maxDate: date2,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var r = [true, ""];
                if (dateList === null) {
                    r[1] = "dp-highlight-unknown";
                } else {
                    var key = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date);
                    if (key in dateList) {
                        r[1] = "dp-highlight-available";
                        r[2] = dateList[key].join(", ");
                    }
                }
                return r;
            }
        });
        $("#tour_region").on("change", function(){
            var region = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/dates?region=" + region, {
                "alt": "json",
                "start-min": $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date1),
                "start-max": $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date(date2.getTime() + 86400000)),
                "orderby": "starttime",
                "max-results": 100
            }, function(data) {
                dateList = {};
                $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, entry) {
                    var key = entry.gd$when[0].startTime.substr(0, 10);
                    if (key in dateList == false) {
                        dateList[key] = [];
                    }
                    dateList[key].push(entry.title.$t);
                });
                $("form #date").datepicker("refresh");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax({type : 'JSON'})`.  I would sugget `console.log(data)` out to see if you actually have a `data.feed.entry` hierarchy in your data

Comment: well, as the error says variable entry is undefined. Can you post the `data ` variable that you got in response here?

Comment: Return of console.log(data).
["2015-04-12", "2015-04-11", "2015-04-26", "2015-03-27", "2015-04-17", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-24", "2015-04-03", "2015-04-03", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-21", "2015-04-18", "2015-03-19", "2015-03-17", "2015-04-17", "2015-04-20", "2015-04-21", "2015-04-15", "2015-03-17", "2015-04-06", "2015-03-24", "2015-04-10", "2015-03-30", "2015-03-24", "2015-03-10", "2015-04-20", "2015-04-17", "2015-04-23", "2015-03-27"]

Comment: 'feed' is unndefined, rather than 'entry'. This can be tricky to catch until you're used to seeing it, but "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entry' of undefined" is really giving you more information about 'feed', than 'entry', because feed is the variable that's undefined. Effectively, because you have data.feed.entry and data.feed is undefined, your call is sort of like data.undefined.entry, and since undefined doesn't have a property called 'entry', you're getting the error. The pertinent bit is not that entry is missing, but that feed is returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This permits the date picker to only show dates returned from the .getJSON.  Thanks everyone.

```
 var dateList = null;
  $(function() {    
  var date1 = new Date;
  date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  date1.setDate(1);

var date2 = new Date;
date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 12, 0);

$("form #date").datepicker({
    minDate: date1,
    maxDate: date2,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {                 
        var r = [false, ""];
        if (dateList === null) {
            r[1] = "dp-highlight-unknown";
        } else {
            var key = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date);                        
            if ($.inArray(key, dateList) != -1) {
                r[0] = true;                            
                r[1] = "dp-highlight-available";                            
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
}); 

$("#tour_region").on("change", function(){
    var region = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("/dates?region=" + region, {
        "alt": "json",
        "start-min": $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date1),
        "start-max": $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date(date2.getTime() + 86400000)),
        "orderby": "starttime",
        "max-results": 100
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        dateList = [];
        $.each(data, function(i, entry) {               
            if ($.inArray(entry, dateList) == -1) {
                dateList.push(entry);
            }               
        });
        $("form #date").datepicker("refresh");
    });
 });        
});
```